# How do I call a Javascript Function using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, enter

I i'd like this javascript function to be called by a jquery script:

```
document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)
```

I'm also using Caret as the coding program, I also use a Chromebook.

Comment: use `on` instead of `live`, let me know how it goes

Comment: Is there any click event for `#submit`?

Comment: doesn't work, maybe chrome doesn't like Jquery?

Comment: "submit" is the id of the button, when clicked, it's supposed to use this code:

Comment: document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)

Comment: How does the html look like? (that is relevant)

Comment: <input type=button value="Google Search" id="submit" onclick="document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)">

Comment: Don't you have an html-element named search-box? Does the function get executed?

Comment: No, but the box's code is: its: <input maxlength=2048 size=55 id="search-box">

Answer (score 1):

[`live` for event handling was removed in jQuery 1.9, you are using 1.11.](https://api.jquery.com/live/), Try using `on` instead. Chrome works fine.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/359/

Also check that your keyup is returning the `13` you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-box').on("keyup", function(event) {
    $('#submit').click();
});
});
```

If you input anything in the label on keyup you'll see the hello world.

`if(event.keyCode == '13')` would be for the `enter` or `return` key